# Is that correct $\mathbb R^2\cong\mathbb R$ as measurable spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is that correct $R^2\cong R$ as measurable spaces?
If we consider $R$ and $R^2$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebras, is there measurable map from  $R$ to $R^2$ with measurable inverse?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465128/are-the-measurable-spaces-mathbbrn-bor-mathbbrn-and-mathbbrm)

Comment: @Mateusz Kwaśnicki: that one is about the Borel sigma-algabras, not Lebesgue.

Comment: @Qfwfq: Technically: yes. However, if measure spaces are isomorphic, so are their completions.

Comment: I think (but should check the details) that there is an isomorphism of their Borel sigma-algebras that preserves null-sets (idea is: both Borel sigma-algebras can be seen as an inductive limit of $P(\mathbb{N})\to P(\mathbb{N})\to\dots$, and the classes of null-sets  in the limits are in bijection).  So their Lebesgue sigma-algebras are isomorphic too.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: what do you mean? the completion depends on the measure. Maybe what you say is true for *divisible* measures?

Comment: @PietroMajer: The linked Math.SE post asserts that the measure spaces $(\mathbb{R}^n, \operatorname{Bor}(\mathbb{R}^n), \operatorname{Leb}^n)$ are all *isomorphic*. Isomorphic measures have isomorphic completions. (My second comment mentioned *measure spaces*, not just *measurable spaces*).

Comment: ok, clear -- yes, I misread *measure* :)